# How to apply && between 3 $conditions[] ? in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

In Cakephp how can i add apply 'AND' between these lines , $conditions[]= codition1 && codition2 && condition3;

```
$conditions[]= array('Flight.from LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['from']."%");
$conditions[]= array('Flight.to LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['to']."%");
$conditions[]= array('Flight.date LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['date']."%");
```

Comment: Can you please read cakephp Cuk Buk ? There it is given in extremely  detail.

Comment: By default these conditions are applied as AND. So what is your problem now exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$conditions = array(
    'AND' => array(
        'Flight.from LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['from']."%",
        'Flight.to LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['to']."%",
        'Flight.date LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['date']."%"
    )
);
```

Official docs and examples [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions).

Comment: $conditions without [] ?

Comment: Using `$conditions[] = $something` is equal to pushing a value at the end of the array. So in your case the $conditions array had 3 arrays as elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify your query by using:

```
$conditions = array(
      'Flight.from LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['from']."%",
      'Flight.to LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['to']."%",
      'Flight.date LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Flight']['date']."%"
 );
```

You don't actually need the arrays around each field when the conditions are on different fields.  Plus CakePHP will automatically use AND between your conditions.